# Linux Mint (Mate): use xkbcomp to load a keyboard layout on startup

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, keymap

I'd like to load a custom keyboard layout on login, but either it doesn't load or it gets overridden by the default keyboard layout from 'keyboard preferences'. Unfortunately I can't select my layout there, since its not installed the way default keyboard layouts are, but compiled by xkbcomp.

This is the xkbcomp command

```
xkbcomp -I$HOME/.config/xkb/ $HOME/.config/xkb/thinkpad.xkb $DISPLAY
```

It works when entered in the terminal. But when put in /etc/rc.local or .xsession (there followed by the command "mate-session") or run as a 'startup application', the layout doesn't load (or maybe is overridden by the default).

How would I go about this? Or is it possible to install a layout compiled by xkbcomp without hacking .lst and .xml files manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xkbcomp` is an X windows application, you can't run it from `rc.local` because that is run *before* X is started.

It *should* work if you add the command in `$HOME/.xsession` (without the `mate-session`) as long as you have this line in your `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` file:

```
allow-user-xsession
```

If the layout is still not set, it is likely being overwritten by Mate. In that case, try adding a `sleep` call to the command so it gets executed *after* Mate does it's thing:

```
(sleep 10 && xkbcomp -I$HOME/.config/xkb/ $HOME/.config/xkb/thinkpad.xkb $DISPLAY)
```

Possibly helpful:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/run-xmodmap-commands-after-login
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login

Comment: `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` contains `allow-user-xsession`. I've further modified .xsession according to [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession) and now all warnings from xkbcomp show up in `.xsession-errors`, but xkbcomp's changes don't seem to apply.

Comment: @sao well that's a step in the right direction, at least it is running. What are the warnings? Also, you have not mentioned what Desktop Environment you are using.

Comment: it's Linux Mint's Mate, which is a fork of Gnome 2. The warnings are about undefined keycode symbols and unused components [(pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/aU3dusj2). But they are the very same warnings that show up when xkbcomp is run from the terminal, so it should still work.

Comment: @sao yes, at least now you know that the command is being executed. The problem seems to be that Mate is overriding it. You could try adding a `sleep` call to make it run after Mate sets its own keyboard. Something like `sleep 10 && xkbcomp -I$HOME/.config/xkb/ ...`.

Comment: I had to put parens around sleep like `(sleep 10 && xkbcomp -I$HOME/.config/xkb/ ...)` but it worked! Thanks so much!